# Export MXDs files to PDFs using Python

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, mxd

I'm trying to write a python script that will export multiple MXDs to individual PDFs while using a feature class field to rename the pdfs (this can be an optional field, if not check it can copy the mxd file name). I copied a script from ESRI, just need the renaming of pdfs part to work.

import arcpy, os, string

```
#Read input parameters from script tool
mxdList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
outPDFpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Create a new PDF object to store the results
outputPDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(outPDFpath)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
dpi = 300
quality = "BEST"
for item in mxdList:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(item)
    outpdf = item.split('.')[0] + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outpdf, "", 0, 0, dpi, quality)
```

Answer (score 1):

is there a question here? I am guessing that this code does not work? You aren't doing anything with the list objects to use them as pdf names. you'll have to use some for loop to get each file name from the list:

```
 for item in mxdList:
    outputPDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(outPDFpath + "\" + item)
```

That is just hacked together off the top of my head. Try something similar.

for [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) you might try

```
outputPDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(os.path.join(outPDFpath, item))
```

Comment: Try using `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation. Also the second `outputPDF` is probably supposed to be `outputPDFpath`.

Comment: @blah238 updated per your comments

Comment: Oh I meant `outPDFpath`. Anyways, we need to know what the real question is.

Comment: he does state that he needs to get the renaming part to work. But, overall, the question does seem a bit abrupt